# existence of martingale having a given terminal law and deterministic quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-processes

I wonder whether there exists a continuous-time martingale satisfying the following: let $\mu$ be a centered probability measure whose support is compact (one can assume, if necessary, that support of $\mu$ is a finite set contained in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of zero).

Then, Does there exist a (bounded) martingale $X_t$ such that $X_0=0$ and it has terminal law $\mu$ (either at some finite terminal time $T$ or at infinity), and that its quadratic variation $dXdX$ is DETERMINISTIC?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want $T$ to be deterministic, or a stopping time, or what?

Comment: That sounds a lot live Skorohod embeding problem have a look on the web there is so much material on this

Comment: Dear Nate, I was hoping that $T$ would be a constant time, but then the claim might not be true...